# I need to create json string as per below using java:

Tags: java, json

I need to create json string as per below using java: under **ADDTNLINFO** element how to add multiple elements as **Tag** .could any one help please ?

```
 {
       "ADDTNLINFO": 
        {
                "Tag": 
                  {
                    "name": "a",
                    "value": "10"
                  },
                "Tag": 
                  {
                    "name": "a b",
                    "value": "20"
                  },
                "Tag": 
                 {
                    "name": "a b c",
                    "value": "30"
                 }
         }
 }
```

Comment: Well, I'd use a JSON library. I'm pretty sure there are *lots* of examples of generating JSON from Java. What research have you performed so far, and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
List<Dto> beans = service.something();
Gson gson = new Gson();
// convert your list to json
String jsonCartList = gson.toJson(beans);
```

You need to add Dependency for Google gson and it will according to your requirement